# Ionic View and ionic run command gives different results - ios

Tags: ios, testing, ionic-framework, release, difference

If I test app in Ionic View on Iphone everything works great, but when I use run command to see app on real device with splashscreen it uses different rendering engine.

Shows up lags when clicks and some delays during execution.

There is a way to get the same results in published app as in Ionic View?

If no - what is a bonus of using Ionic View to test something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with ionic view, i think that it is a waste of time. You can use ionic view if you are in the beginning but i think that the best practice is to run everything on real device.

For example oauthentication works fine in my device but in ionic view sometimes crashes.